# Can I apply 2 patches to the kernel?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, patch

I am working on a project that requires me to install a Real Time Preempt kernel. I have found a [tutorial](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup) and [Linus Torvalds' readme](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/admin-guide) (Creator of Linux kernel) that both explain that to install a vanilla kernel tree start with the following:

```
xz -cd linux-4.4.86.tar.xz | tar xvf -
cd linux-4.4.86
```

Then they each differ in what patch to add. The tutorial says I should download and apply:

Patch 2

```
xzcat ../patch-4.4.86-rt99.patch.xz | patch -p1
```

While Linus Torvald's repo says to execute:

Patch 2

```
xz -cd ../patch-4.4.86.xz | patch -p1
```

I know the first patch is required for my kernel to run in realtime, but is there a problem with me applying the second patch?

When I apply the second patch I get the following error message (which tells me I probably shouldn't be applying two patches):

```
xzcat ../patch-4.4.86.xz | patch -p1
patching file Documentation/arm64/silicon-errata.txt
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

From what I've read, a patch just reads the differences between two files and corrects them, so would applying the second patch `patch-4.9.47` remove the patch for RT or concatenate it? Any insight as to which step to take would be very helpful.

Comment: Not vested in this but I think the more recent will remove the older one. I thin that's how patches aught to work.

Comment: But doesn't each patch add some features, why would they be mutually exclusive?

Comment: Yes they do what I meant was modify the older one not remove, sorry for using remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I only needed to apply the one patch. It is certainly possible to apply more than 1 path but this may cause compatibility issues.